# store other data in signup function Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm modifying the signup function that store user's data( email and password). I wish to include more data such as phone number, name and national ID. I tried but in mysql database it doesn't show anything. Here is what I have done :

```
public function signup(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only([
        'national_id' ,
        'name' ,
        'phone',

    ]);
    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'sometimes|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'sometimes|min:3',
        'national_id' => 'required','unique:national_id',

    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors()->all());
    }
    try {
        $user = $this->users->create($request->except('roles', 'permissions'));
        if (!$user->id) {
            return $this->response->error('could_not_create_user', 500);
        }


        $hasToReleaseToken = Config::get('boilerplate.signup_token_release');
        if ($hasToReleaseToken) {
            $user->national_id = $request->national_id;
            return $this->login($request);
        }
        return $this->response->created();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->response->error($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```

when I `dd($request->national_id` it shows me the national_id data in postman, but in my database it's NULL.

Comment: Have you added the new fields to the $fillable array in your model?

Comment: yes I did but I think I haven't stored it the data yet and I don't know where to do that

Comment: Did you use the make:auth command?

Comment: Have you run 'artisan migrate' after changing the database schema?

Comment: yes. it used to work but then suddenly stopped.